# Probability and statistics problem

Tags: probability

Three players $A,B,C$ take turns in rolling a dice. what is the probability that 
i) $A$ is the second player to get a six for the first time?
ii) $A$ is the last player to get a six for the first time?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: Good Question but since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post

Comment: For the first part it is clear that the favorable cases can occur in the 4, 7 ,10 .... turn i.r for 3r+1 chances.Considering the 4 turn (2 for A) we get the probability as 2x(5/6)^4x(1/6)^2. Generalizing this the probability is : summation(r=1 to inf) 2r*(5/6)^(3r+1)*(1/6)^2. however the answer I get is incorrect. Similarly for the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** (i) The event can happen on A's second toss, or third, or fourth, and so on. Let $A_k$ be the event that it happens on her $(k+1)$-th toss.

So A must have tossed something other than a $6$ $k$ times, and then a $6$. This has probability $(5/6)^k(1/6)$.

Also, exactly one of B or C  must have gotten at least one $6$ on her first $k$ tosses. This has probability $2(1-(5/6)^k)(5/6)^k$.

Thus the required probability is 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (5/6)^k(1/6)(2)(1-(5/6)^k)(5/6)^k.$$
To evaluate, we need to sum two infinite geometric series.

(ii) A similar strategy will work.

Comment: It helps. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. Another way to do (ii) is to let $p_2$ be the answer to (i), and let $p_1$ the probability A is first (easiest to find). Then probability A is third is $1-(p_1+p_2)$.